# Installing TOMCAT on AIX 7.1

Tags: aix, tomcat

After installing a lot of packages I finally got ./configure to work, just to get a horrible message

**Host support**:-
 checking C flags dependant on host system type... failed
 configure: error: Unsupported operating system "aix7.1.0.0"

**Versions:**
AIX 7.1 & TomCat 7.0.55 & JAVA 1.6

Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to make/build/compile. Just install tomcat then (vi etc/profile)

profile had following added on end:

- JDK_HOME=/usr/java6/jre;export JDK_HOME
- JAVA_HOME=/usr/java6;export JAVA_HOME
- CATALINA_HOME=/apps/tomcat;export CATALINA_HOME
- PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JDK_HOME:$JDK_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME:$CATALINA_HOME/bin;export PATH

after that I did following 3 steps from command prompt:

1. $CATALINA_HOME
2. ./setclasspath.sh
3. ./startup.sh

I got the following output:

- Using CATALINA_BASE: /apps/tomcat Using CATALINA_HOME: /apps/tomcat
- Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /apps/tomcat/temp
- Using JRE_HOME: /usr/java6
- Using CLASSPATH: /apps/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/apps/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
- Tomcat started.

---

command --> catalina.sh version

- Using CATALINA_BASE:   /apps/tomcat
- Using CATALINA_HOME:   /apps/tomcat
- Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /apps/tomcat/temp
- Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java6
- Using CLASSPATH:       /apps/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/apps/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
- Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
- Server built:   Jul 18 2014 05:34:04
- Server number:  7.0.55.0
- OS Name:        AIX
- OS Version:     7.1
- Architecture:   ppc
- JVM Version:    pap3260sr11-20120806_01 (SR11)
- JVM Vendor:     IBM Corporation